# Different center element background in horizontal RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

[image]

I want a horizontal recycler view like this. I tried changing implementations of OnScrolledBy in layout manager and adding onScrollListener but nothing is working out. 
This is the closest I got:

[image]

In this, I have changed layoutManager's implementation with this code:

```
  @Override public int scrollHorizontallyBy(int dx, RecyclerView.Recycler recycler,
      RecyclerView.State state)
  {
    int scrolled = super.scrollHorizontallyBy(dx, recycler, state);
    float midpoint = getWidth() / 2.f;
    float d0 = 0.f;
    float d1 = mShrinkDistance * midpoint;
    float s0 = 1.f;
    float s1 = 1.f - mShrinkAmount;
    for (int i = 0; i < getChildCount(); i++)
    {
      Log.d(TAG, "scrollHorizontallyBy: Child Count"+getChildCount());
      View child = getChildAt(i);
      Log.d(TAG, "scrollHorizontallyBy: Child "+i+" text::"+((TextView)getChildAt(i).findViewById(R.id.txtPeriodDate)).getText().toString());
      float childMidpoint = (getDecoratedRight(child) + getDecoratedLeft(child)) / 2.f;
      Log.d(TAG, "scrollHorizontallyBy: Child MidPoint"+childMidpoint);
      float d = Math.min(d1, Math.abs(midpoint - childMidpoint));
      Log.d(TAG, "scrollHorizontallyBy: Value of d"+d);
      float scale = s0 + (s1 - s0) * (d - d0) / (d1 - d0);
      Log.d(TAG, "scrollHorizontallyBy: Scale"+scale);
      if(Math.abs(1.f-scale)<=0.05)
      {
        View frontView = child.findViewById(R.id.llPeriodFrontLayout);
        frontView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        frontView.refreshDrawableState();
        View backView = child.findViewById(R.id.llPeriodBackLayout);
        backView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        backView.refreshDrawableState();
/*        RecyclerView.LayoutParams layoutParams =
            (RecyclerView.LayoutParams) child.getLayoutParams();
        layoutParams.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
        currentRecyclerView.getLayoutManager().getChildAt(i).setLayoutParams(layoutParams);*/
      }else
      {
        View backView = currentRecyclerView.getLayoutManager().getChildAt(i).findViewById(R.id.llPeriodBackLayout);
        backView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        backView.refreshDrawableState();
        View frontView = currentRecyclerView.getLayoutManager().getChildAt(i).findViewById(R.id.llPeriodFrontLayout);
        frontView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        frontView.refreshDrawableState();
        /*
        nonCentralItemHeight = currentRecyclerView.getLayoutManager().getChildAt(i).getHeight();
        nonCentralMargin =
            Math.round(centralItemHeight / 2.f) - Math.round(nonCentralItemHeight / 2.f);
        RecyclerView.LayoutParams layoutParams =
            (RecyclerView.LayoutParams) currentRecyclerView.getLayoutManager().getChildAt(i).getLayoutParams();
        layoutParams.setMargins(0, nonCentralMargin, 0, 0);
        currentRecyclerView.getLayoutManager().getChildAt(i).setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        */
      }
/*      child.setScaleX(scale);
      child.setScaleY(scale);*/
    }

    return scrolled;
  }
```

This was actually a code for zooming central item in recycler view which I have tweaked. This is my code for a normal item(in yellow):

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/flPeriod"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/dimen_margin_5"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/dimen_margin_5"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:ignore="MissingPrefix"
    >
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/llPeriodBackLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/selected_day_background"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        />
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/llPeriodFrontLayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/filled_day"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        />
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/llPeriodTextLayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >
      <TextView
          android:id="@+id/txtPeriodDay"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:maxLength="3"
          android:text="@string/app_name"
          android:textAllCaps="true"
          android:textColor="@android:color/white"
          android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_19"
          fontPath="@string/font_semibold"
          />
      <TextView
          android:id="@+id/txtPeriodDate"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text="@string/app_name"
          android:textColor="@android:color/white"
          android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_19"
          fontPath="@string/font_semibold"
          />
    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Can anyone suggest a library or help me with this?

Comment: try this without using third party lib http://www.devexchanges.info/2016/06/carousel-layout-with-viewpager-in.html

Comment: @NileshRathod Can't we do it with recyclerview?

Comment: try this https://github.com/Azoft/CarouselLayoutManager

Comment: https://github.com/huang3eng/CustomLayoutManager

Comment: You can get idea from this https://github.com/moondroid/CoverFlow

Comment: @saurabhdixit don't point to any random code

Comment: @NileshRathod I tried https://github.com/Azoft/CarouselLayoutManager but seems like it doesn't support different item types. I have 2 item types for recyclerview, when I implemented it, it ignored one of them.

Comment: @RushiMThakker https://github.com/huang3eng/CustomLayoutManager

Comment: or try this https://github.com/yarolegovich/DiscreteScrollView

Comment: @NileshRathod I don't think I am looking for that. I will go with https://github.com/Azoft/CarouselLayoutManager and try to tweak source code or try something in default recyclerview

Comment: @RushiMThakker than you need to create your custom recyclerview

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149996/discussion-between-rushi-m-thakker-and-nilesh-rathod).